# Can I write something that uses type deduction as in make_tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I can either write `make_tuple<int,bool>(1,true)` or write `make_tuple(1,true)` and the compiler will deduce it's types.   Is this ability available for code I write or is it somehow built into the compiler to which I can't access?

Answer (score 1):

Template argument deduction (the proper name for this) is mandated by the standard for all function templates. The process that should be followed is explained in C++11, section 14.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
template <typename... Ts>
tuple<Ts...> my_make_tuple(Ts... ts)
{
    return tuple<Ts...>(ts...);
}
```

NOTE: This doesn't use perfect forwarding or any other tricks. It's just an example of how you can write your own function that does argument deduction.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will be able to deduce the types provided that deduction is unambiguous. Otherwise, you may need to provide hint for compiler in form of those template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The make_tuple function is just a normal function template.  You could do the same thing yourself.